# ToggleClass não está funcionando

Tags: jquery, jquery-toggleclass

Eu estou tentando criar uma lista de elementos com elementos escondidos dentro de cada tag li. Quando clica na li, os elementos escondidos aparecem, porém quando clico de novo eles não fecham.

Esse é o código JS:

```
$('.box-content-minhas-ofertas .offer-list').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).find('.title').click(function(e) {
        $(el).find('.open').removeClass('open')
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open')
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="offer-list">
            <li class="offer">
                <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
                    <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="description">Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.</div>
                    <div class="action">
                        <div class="price">R$119,90</div>
                        <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar()">Contratar oferta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="offer">
                <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
                    <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="description">[MODAL ERRO] Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.</div>
                    <div class="action">
                        <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar_Erro()">Contratar oferta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
.open {
    .content{
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    .content { 
        display: none; 
        height: 0; 
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione o código a pergunta não uma imagem, também pode colocar um código executavel usado `Ctrl + m`

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quer. Posta o código executavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os seus seletores estão alinhados de forma errada, veja no exemplo abaixo como deveria ser (explicação comentada no snippet):

```js
 //Selecionando o elemento pai, e abrindo o loop pelas 'lis' dentro de 'offer-list'
$('.box-content-minhas-ofertas,  .offer-list').find('li').each(function(e) { 
   var li = $(this);

  //$(this) é cada 'li',, e em cada 'li' buscamos um '.title' para atribuir um evento 'click'
  $(this).find('.title').click(function(e){

    //Removemos a classe .open do outro elemento dentro de offer-list
    $('.box-content-minhas-ofertas,  .offer-list').find('.open').removeClass('open'); 

    //Adicionamos a classe open a proxima div dentro da li, ou seja, a div após .title 
    $(this).next('div').toggleClass('open');

  });

})
```

```css
.open {
    .content{
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    .content { 
        display: none; 
        height: 0; 
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content-minhas-ofertas">
<ul class="offer-list">
  <li class="offer">
    <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
      <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="description">Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.
       </div>
       <div class="action">
        <div class="price">R$119,90</div>
          <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar()">Contratar oferta</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="offer">
    <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
      <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="description">[MODAL ERRO] Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.
      </div>
      <div class="action">
        <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar_Erro()">Contratar oferta</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Explicando o porque seu código não funciona**

Nesta parte:

```
$('.box-content-minhas-ofertas .offer-list').each(function(i, el) {
```

Você está tentando percorrer como se houvessem vários `'.offer-list'` ao invés de percorrer pelo `'li'`, sendo assim, neste trecho:

```
$(el).find('.title').click(function(e) {
```

O 'el' está sendo atribuído a `.offer-list` não a `offer`, por este motivo, o trecho:

```
$(el).find('.open').removeClass('open')
$(this).parent().toggleClass('open')
```

Estes métodos estarão sempre sendo atribuídos ao mesmo elemento, não efetuando o que é esperado, que é a alternância entre qual `content` estará aberto.

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery não precisa fazer loop `.each` para capturar clicks em uma coleção de elementos. Basta selecionar a coleção e usar `.click`:

```
$('.box-content-minhas-ofertas .offer-list li').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.content').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Outro problema está no CSS aninhado que está usando. O correto é adicionar a classe `.open` à classe `.content` que fará com que a `div` fique visível:

```
.content.open{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.content{ 
     display: none; 
     height: 0; 
     padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
$('.box-content-minhas-ofertas .offer-list li').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.content').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.content.open{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.content{ 
     display: none; 
     height: 0; 
     padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content-minhas-ofertas">
   <ul class="offer-list">
      <li class="offer">
          <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
              <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <div class="description">Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.</div>
              <div class="action">
                  <div class="price">R$119,90</div>
                  <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar()">Contratar oferta</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="offer">
          <div class="title">Liberty Web 10GB
              <img src="images/arrow-down-select.png" data-src-ac="images/arrow-down-select-ac.png" alt="Seta" class="arrow-down">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <div class="description">[MODAL ERRO] Plano com franquia de 10GB para acesso a Internet. possibilita recontratar uma franquia de 1GB de dados após atingir 100% de consumo da franquia original.</div>
              <div class="action">
                  <button onclick="modal_Ofertas_Contratar_Erro()">Contratar oferta</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo :) Valeu!

Comment: De nada! Já sabe como funciona o site? O que fazer quando uma resposta lhe atendeu? Marcar ✓ em uma única resposta. Abs!

Comment: Ah, não sabia. Marquei agora. Obrigada! abs

Comment: @FernandaClara Olá Fernanda. Vi que desmarcou a resposta. Não deu certo, achou a outra resposta melhor ou foi engano? Desculpe, estou perguntando porque acontece muito com usuários novos, que acham que devem marcar ✓ em todas respostas sem saber que está desmarcando a que já foi marcada. Obg!

Comment: @FernandaClara também gostaria de saber o motivo de ter desmarcado, na minha opinião a resposta do dvd atende melhor sua  dúvida

Comment: @dvd, eu consegui resolver melhor o meu problema com o que foi proposto pelo AnthraxisBR. Eu precisava que o 'open' aparecesse quando clicasse no 'title' e pra fazer isso funcionar eu precisei usar each.

Comment: @FernandaClara tranquilo! Abs!

Comment: valeu @dvd! Abs